# Is it possible to wait for two different events in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to kafka and I'm trying to see if it could replace my current ETL.
My main hard point is that I need a way to wait for two distinct events as prerequisite.

Example:

```
Given the topics T1, T2 and T3,
When I get an event E3(E1, E2) on topic T3,
Then the event E3 cannot be processed until E1 has been processed on T1 and E2 has been process on T2
```

My basic need is to make sure that before I try to import E3, its corresponding functional prerequisite have been imported.

I have read through the documentation and I'm well aware that this kind of prerequisite isn't exactly suited to Kafka philosophy.

Is what I describe feasible ? if so, which way should I go ?

Comment: You would need to encode this logic in your own user code. Ie, for each record you receive via `poll()` you need to check if all requirements are met before processing the even (if not, you might need to buffer the even until the requirements are met. It might be helpful to pause()/resume() partitions. The overall code will most likely be quite complex.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax, my other idea was to implement this logic inside an actor model, such as AKKA. If I have to do it manually, at least I'll have the Actor ecosystem to rely on.